# Hangfire.io: How to create job using server type?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a c# client app and service which hosts job server.
Example: 
Service has class and 3 methods

```
public class TransferData
{
..
TransferToSQLServer
TransferToRDS
TransferToAzure
}
```

Client application knows nothing about this class.
How client can create jobs to transfer data via one of these methods?
Must client application have copy of this class in their code to know this type for a job creation?

Comment: What the kind of data you want transfer? Files?

Comment: It is a data, nvarchar(MAX) and binary(MAX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s the good practice to transfer data between diferent systems, thas it, different domains, you must integrate using a service bus. And usualy service bus are implemented with queue servers, like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ. In this case, the both involved systems need have knowledge of a simple POCO class, called of Contract.

This contracts must be knowledge for all applications and are the messages that you transfer between applications. When a application 'publish' a message, you can have many other applications 'listening' a exchange waiting messages. And after receive the message, do the necessary processing.

Using this method, you can integrate applications and different languages.

Bellow a basic example transfering basic messages (simple strings):
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

You can yet add a above layer like MassTransit (free) or NServiceBus (commercial)
An example:
http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html